# How to make Ruby on Rails model relation with custom string column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have Customer and Subscription models in my Ruby on Rails app.

```
Customer
id: ID
stripe_costumer_id: String

Subscription
id: ID
stripe_customer_id: String
```

I want to make a relation one to many between there two tables but use stripe_customer_id as foreign key.

I tried so far:

```
Subscription
belongs_to :paywall_customer, class_name: 'Customer', foreign_key: :stripe_customer_id

Customer
has_one :paywall_subscription, class_name: 'Subscription', foreign_key: :stripe_customer_id
```

The problem is then when I try to create a new subscription I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Customer must exist
```

I would be grateful if you could help me achieve to make posibile to get the relation between these two tables using stripe_costumer_id that is also a string in this case.

Comment: is there a reason you specifically need this to be a 1:N? this could just be a join table between the two (then you could do something like ```has_many :subscriptions, through: :customer_subscriptions```)

Answer (score 0):

You are conflating data (stripe_customer_id) with relational references (id). It is not advisable to fight the Rails paradigm, the id field should be the foreign key. The stripe_customer_id field is a value that pertains to a customer, so it should just be a field in the customers table and not in the subscriptions table.

For one-to-many it should be:

```rb
# in app/models/customer.rb
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subscriptions
end

# in app/models/subscription.rb
# it has a column 'customer_id'
class Subscription < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

If you try to configure the relationship in non-Rails ways, you are bound to end up with problems. Rails is opinionated, and we are obligated to conform to its opinions. But it's a small price to pay b/c it works so well.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

You need to add `primary_key: :stripe_customer_id` to the associations.

And since you want a one-to-many relationship: Customer `has_many :paywall_subscriptions`

```
Customer
  has_many :paywall_subscriptions, class_name: 'Subscription', foreign_key: :stripe_customer_id, primary_key: :stripe_customer_id

Subscription
  belongs_to :paywall_customer, class_name: 'Customer', foreign_key: :stripe_customer_id, primary_key: :stripe_customer_id
```

To create a Subscription, you must have `stripe_customer_id` field filled in. And a Customer with that `stripe_customer_id` must already exist.

---

ORGINAL

This can work if you add the model `StripeCustomer`; we store the `stripe_customer_id` string inside the `uid` field.

```
Customer
id: ID
stripe_customer_id: String

Subscription
id: ID
stripe_customer_id: String

StripeCustomer
id: ID
uid: String
```

```
Customer
  belongs_to :stripe_customer, primary_key: :uid
  has_many :subscriptions, through: :stripe_customer

Subscription
  belongs_to :stripe_customer, primary_key: :uid
  has_one :customer, through: :stripe_customer

StripeCustomer
  has_one :customer, primary_key: :uid
  has_many :subscriptions, primary_key: :uid
```